# Woodboring insects in roof

Tags: roof

I  have a roof built relatively recently over a concrete slab. It's a reinforced concrete frame and this is how things are normally done. The roof done with pine wood and then has it has concrete tiles over it. One problem...wood-boring insects have attacked it, especially on the north and north-east side (much less sun on that side.)

After reading I seem to have some options: 
1. Aluminum Phosphide. Even though I can't cover it, I can put a lot of it and hope for the best, at least it costs next to nothing. Problem is that it reacts with copper and can damage a lot of stuff there.

2. Spray the wood with chemicals and I have tried it but the wood has been  painted with some sort of tar and don't know if it works. I am not sure that they are still working or not inside. 
   [image: roof]

So, what should I do : ) ? Drilling every few inches is a no-no since it weakens it and I have tried to insert fungicide /insecticide (<< edited) with a syringe on the exit holes. **Do think this tar thingy lets enough down if I keep spraying?**

Also, I am working to lower humidity.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your location this may be a job for a pro. You don't want to poison your family and you want the bugs dead before the roof fails. I know in several states the stuff that works can only be purchased by a certified tech usually working for a pest control company.

Comment: actually it is a fungicide and insecticide, in one (has a greenish look). My family would be out for a week or so if I do it myself. There no real pros here for that. The wood should have been treated before, but it wasn't.

Comment: Spray insect killer on the particular spot